# Matlab hdl coding

Tags: matlab, vhdl, hdl-coder

I received this error message when I try the conversion via HDL coder. Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
function [p_max,t_max]=ricmax(g,fs)


    valmin=0.40*max(g);                
    [p_max,t_max]=findpeaks(g,'minpeakheight',valmin);
    t_max=t_max/fs;


    end
```

error:

```
??? Expected Y to be one of these types: double, single.
Instead its type was embedded.fi.
```

Input signal:

```
fs=1000;
g=sin(1:10)*rand(10);
```

Comment: findpeaks function does not support fixed-point types.

Comment: How do I convert this code with HDL encoder?

Comment: I guess that function is not supported for HDL generation since floating point is not synthesizable.

Comment: Not everything can simply be converted to HDL. converting matlab to hdl is like the process of drawing a tree: you can at best make a projection of the tree on the paper, but you can never capture its full essence ;)